# AngularJS - ng-include closes unclosed tags in a HTML file

Tags: html, angularjs

I have one AngularJS application.

In **index.html**  I have one ng-view and two ng-icludes.

Here is how my **index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- CSS imports -->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-include src="'header1.html'"></div>
 <div ng-view></div>
<div ng-include src="'footer1.html'"></div>
</body>
<!-- JS imports -->
</html>
```

My **header1.html** is this

```
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
```

As you can see I have **not closed** any **div** tags here.
And my **footer1.html** is the one which closes the tags

```
            </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

In between I have the **ng-view** which will change based path.

But the problem is when I run the application, The first html closes all the tags before the **ng-view**. When I do "Inspect element" in Chrome, I see this:

```
<div ng-include="" src="'header1.html'">
    <div class="main-container ng-scope">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-view> ... </div>
<div ng-include="" src="'footer1.html'">                        

                <!-- /.col -->
            <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- /.main-container -->
</div>
```

All the **divs** are closed. So it does not apply the style to whole page. Why is that so? How can I get in the other way?

(Basically I want to change the templates of header and footer based on the path. Now it is hard coded for testing only.)

**EDIT 1**

Part of **app.js**

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      })
     .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
       controller: 'homeController'
    })
   .when('/profile', {
       templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
       controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

For login and register my header and footer styles should be different and for other pages I should have other styles.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because it's async call. Just copy paste code from header and foter to index and problem solved.
You will be not able to do what you want.

Comment: If so, I could do that already. But based on the path, I want to change the templates of header and footer

Comment: Than include header and footer in ng-view template and ship it together with location change.

Comment: How? Can you give tell in more detail?

Comment: In template where is <div ng-view></div>, you must see template name of that route in route config.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT 1**. I have added my `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can still do what you are trying to do with a change to your page eg

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- CSS imports -->
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-include src="'body1.html'"></div>
</body>
<!-- JS imports -->
</html>
```

body1

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div ng-view></div>     
       </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

If you want to factor out your footer for example put another ng-include there or a directive if appropriate. It seems to make sense that your directives or templates should always close tags in the same file as the open one.

Edit1

body2

```
<div class="main-container-alternative">
    <div class="main-content-alternative">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div ng-view></div>     
       </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

Comment: Ok. For some pages I can have same div. So this is fine. For some other pages, I want completely different styles. So what should I do?

Comment: Suppose you want a completely different page header then pull that out like edit1

Answer (score -1):

So what you have to do at each template in tempalte just add header and footer eg: 
login.html

```
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div >
                         This is my login stuff
                     </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

register.html

```
 <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div >
                             This is my register stuff
                         </div>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

So on each template you must provide own header and footer.
And than index html looks like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- CSS imports -->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
<!-- JS imports -->
</html>
```

Comment: I thought the common styles I put in common. What if I use `ng-switch`?

Comment: Add a header and footer in each template will result in code duplication, he is including the header and footer to don't have code duplication, so your solution can't be accepted